# How can I do exception handling in C#?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using a `try`/`catch` block. The query is executed successfully and gives a message, but after that it gives nullvalue massage for Householdid column which is foreign key, although the text box took the value and data is inserted. I want that this error message is not shown.

```cs
private void OK_HouseHoldMember_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Datagrid view

     string ConString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=HouseHoldProfile;Integrated Security=True";
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConString);
     conn.Open();
     textBox13.Text = textBox3.Text;

     try
     {
         foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
         {
             textBox13.Text = textBox3.Text;

             SqlCommand sqlCommand_3 = new SqlCommand();
             sqlCommand_3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             sqlCommand_3.Connection = conn;
             sqlCommand_3.CommandText = "InsertHouseHoldMembertbl";

             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HouseHoldID", dr.Cells["آی دی خانواده"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", dr.Cells["جنسیت"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", dr.Cells["سن تکمیل شده"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", dr.Cells["حالت مدنی"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HeadRelationship", dr.Cells["قرابت با رییس خانواده"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student", dr.Cells["شاگرد"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EducationLevelMature", dr.Cells["سطح سواد"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HighestEducationLevel", dr.Cells["بلند ترین درجه تحصیل"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job", dr.Cells["شغل اصلی"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemporaryJob", dr.Cells["شغل فرعی"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Disability", dr.Cells["معلولیت"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addict", dr.Cells["اعتیاد"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addictType", dr.Cells["نوعیت اعتیاد"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pregnant", dr.Cells["حاملگی"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MilkChildwoman", dr.Cells["طفل سو تغذی"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnderNutrationChild", dr.Cells["طفل سو تغذی"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
             sqlCommand_3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CauseNotSchool", dr.Cells["علت مکتب نرفتن"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);

             sqlCommand_3.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: `The query is executed successfully and gives a message` - these two statements contradict because the only message there is is in the case of an exception. `although the text box took the value and data is inserted` - you are executing the command multiple times without a transaction. Apparently some rows succeed and are inserted into the database, then a row fails (and you are now stuck with partial data in the database).

Comment: If you don't want to show any error, you have to remove the line "MessageBox.Show". But probably you want something else, than not showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are coercing the value of `HouseHoldID`, which might be allowing it to get through without throwing an exception.

I suggest trying to remove the:

> `?? DBNull.Value`

From that line, so that it throws an exception if it's `null`, as the value shouldn't be `null`.